# Difference between Binder.bind using Key and without Key in Google Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

What is the difference between the two while providing binding using Google Guice?

```
bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class)
bind(A.class).to(Key.get(AImpl.class))
```

Comment: Did you mean `Key.get(AImpl.class)`?  Otherwise there's a big difference :)

Comment: Hi @TavianBarnes
Thanks for pointing that typo, It is in fact Key.get(AImpl.class), and so the question what is the difference here.

Comment: Then there is no difference.  In fact, the `Class` version is implemented [on  top of](https://github.com/google/guice/blob/abc78c361d9018da211690b673accb580a52abf2/core/src/com/google/inject/internal/BindingBuilder.java#L61) the `Key` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If used the way you do in your example, there is no difference. The first line binds to exactly the class AImpl, the second line binds to a class that matches (isassignable from) A.class.
Using the Key wrapper will allow you to bind on generic types and annotated types if you are using more complex use cases.

Comment: Apologies for the typo, the second case is in fact with Key.get(AImpl.class), does that mean for simpler cases, both the variations are alike?